# Generate code on new lines with the vscode vscode.window.activeTextEditor.edit function

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Hello all I am writing a vscode extension that generates template code based upon the language you are using when you click a button. However the code generated is not on new lines although the co-ordinates are correct.

```
import * as vscode from 'vscode';
import "typescript";
import "./constants";

let myStatusBar : vscode.StatusBarItem;

export function activate({ subscriptions }: vscode.ExtensionContext) {
    const codeBoilerplateCommand = 'code-boilerplate.CodeBoilerplate';
    subscriptions.push(vscode.commands.registerCommand(codeBoilerplateCommand, () => {
        const documentFileType = vscode.window.activeTextEditor?.document.languageId;
        const documentFileName = vscode.window.activeTextEditor?.document.fileName;
        const documentFilePath = vscode.window.activeTextEditor?.document.fileName.split('/');

        if (documentFileType === "javascript") {
            vscode.window.activeTextEditor.edit(editBuilder => {
                editBuilder.insert(new vscode.Position(0, 0), 'console.log("Hello World!")');
            });
        }
        else if (documentFileType === "python") {
            vscode.window.activeTextEditor.edit(editBuilder => {
                editBuilder.insert(new vscode.Position(0, 0), 'print("Hello World!")');
            });
        }
        else if (documentFileType === "typescript") {
            vscode.window.activeTextEditor.edit(editBuilder => {
                editBuilder.insert(new vscode.Position(0, 0), 'console.log("Hello World!");');
            });
        }
        else if (documentFileType === "csharp") {
            vscode.window.activeTextEditor.edit(editBuilder => {
                editBuilder.insert(new vscode.Position(0,0), 'using System;');
                editBuilder.insert(new vscode.Position(0,3), 'namespace HelloWorld {');
                editBuilder.insert(new vscode.Position(6,4), 'class HelloWorld {');
                editBuilder.insert(new vscode.Position(9,8), 'static void Main(string[] args) {');
                editBuilder.insert(new vscode.Position(12,12), 'Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");');
                editBuilder.insert(new vscode.Position(14,8), '}');
                editBuilder.insert(new vscode.Position(15,4), '}');
                editBuilder.insert(new vscode.Position(16,0), '}');
            });
        }
        else if (documentFileType === "c") {
            vscode.window.activeTextEditor.edit(editBuilder => {
                editBuilder.insert(new vscode.Position(0,0), '#include <stdio.h>');
                editBuilder.insert(new vscode.Position(1,0), 'int main() {');
                editBuilder.insert(new vscode.Position(2,4), 'printf("Hello World!");');
                editBuilder.insert(new vscode.Position(3,4), 'return 0;');
                editBuilder.insert(new vscode.Position(4,0), '}');
            })
        }
        else if (documentFileType === "cpp") {
            return null;
        }
        else if (documentFileType === "java") {
            return null;
        }
        vscode.window.showInformationMessage("Code Boilerplate Generated! ");
    }));

    myStatusBar = vscode.window.createStatusBarItem(vscode.StatusBarAlignment.Right, 100);
    myStatusBar.command = codeBoilerplateCommand;
    subscriptions.push(myStatusBar);

    subscriptions.push(vscode.window.onDidChangeActiveTextEditor(updateStatusBarItem));
    subscriptions.push(vscode.window.onDidChangeTextEditorSelection(updateStatusBarItem));
    updateStatusBarItem();
}

function updateStatusBarItem(): void {
    myStatusBar.text = `$(new-file) Hello World!`;
    myStatusBar.show();
}

export function deactivate() {
    myStatusBar.dispose();
}
```

For example if I used a C Sharp File I would get

```
using System;namespace HelloWorld {class HelloWorld {static void Main(string[] args) {Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");}}}
```

Where I would expect this with new lines and indented code

```
using System;

namespace HelloWorld {
    class HelloWorld {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I wonder if in thr document that those lines 2-16 do not actually exist and so the edits all go on the same line?  Just a guess.  Can you start with a file that has 16 empty lines and  see if it works?  In other words I don't know that you can create a line simply by making an edit to an additional, not pre-existing, line.

Comment: Note your line 3 Position is swapped: should be `new vscode.Position(3, 0)`.

Comment: why don't you use `registerTextEditorCommand` you get an `TextEditor` and `TextEdit` as arguments

Answer (score 1):

In testing your code, I see that I was correct in the comment above that if there is no pre-existing line 2 in a document you cannot simply

`editBuilder.insert(new vscode.Position(2,3), 'someText');`

and have it work.  The `editBuilder` will not write to a line that isn't already there - it will not automatically create a new line which would be nice.  But instead it appends it to the only line that is there, line 1.

There are two ways around this:

- Best method: Construct your string as a string literal.

```js
let insertString;

// build the cSharp string
insertString = `using System;

namespace HelloWorld {
  class HelloWorld {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
      Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
    }
  }
}`;

// only need one of these for all the insertString's
await vscode.window.activeTextEditor.edit(editBuilder => {
    editBuilder.insert(new vscode.Position(0,0), insertString);
});
```

This works nicely and it is easy to see if your string is correct with the indentation you want.

---

- Insert enough empty lines first then add your edits:

```js
// make these into a loop
await vscode.commands.executeCommand('editor.action.insertLineAfter');
await vscode.commands.executeCommand('editor.action.insertLineAfter');
await vscode.commands.executeCommand('editor.action.insertLineAfter');
await vscode.commands.executeCommand('editor.action.insertLineAfter');
await vscode.commands.executeCommand('editor.action.insertLineAfter');
await vscode.commands.executeCommand('editor.action.insertLineAfter');
await vscode.commands.executeCommand('editor.action.insertLineAfter');
await vscode.commands.executeCommand('editor.action.insertLineAfter');

  // I fixed the Position arguments here
  // note all Position characters are at 0

await vscode.window.activeTextEditor.edit(editBuilder => {
    editBuilder.insert(new vscode.Position(0,0), 'using System;');
    editBuilder.insert(new vscode.Position(2,0), 'namespace HelloWorld {');
    editBuilder.insert(new vscode.Position(3,0), '\tclass HelloWorld {');
    editBuilder.insert(new vscode.Position(4,0), '\t\tstatic void Main(string[] args) {');
    editBuilder.insert(new vscode.Position(5,0), '\t\t\tConsole.WriteLine("Hello World!");');
    editBuilder.insert(new vscode.Position(6,0), '\t\t}');
    editBuilder.insert(new vscode.Position(7,0), '\t}');
    editBuilder.insert(new vscode.Position(8,0), '}');
});
```

> Note on Positions:  Apparently just like writing to lines that don't exist, writing to a character position like `editBuilder.insert(new vscode.Position(6,12).....` will not work on an empty line 6.  There is no character 12 on an empty line.  So I zero'ed the `Position` `characters` and used `\t`'s instead to indent lines as desired.  This is another reason method 1 is preferable.

---

Both methods work but obviously the first is cleaner.  Here is a demo of both methods working back-to-back in the same `activate` function:

[image: editBuilder in a blank document demo]

---

---

> Another trick is to select all the text and run the command `editor.action.formatSelection` **after** you have set the languageId for that file (check if it isn't already set by the user):

```js
const  editor = vscode.window.activeTextEditor;
await vscode.languages.setTextDocumentLanguage(editor.document, 'javascript');

// Note: no attempt to format the insertString here
const insertString = `using System;

    namespace HelloWorld {
    class HelloWorld {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
    Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
    }
    }
    }`;

await editor.edit(editBuilder => {
    editBuilder.insert(new vscode.Position(10,0), insertString);
});

// select all the text and run formatSelection
await vscode.commands.executeCommand('editor.action.selectAll');
await vscode.commands.executeCommand('editor.action.formatSelection');
await vscode.commands.executeCommand('cancelSelection');
```

> That assumes that the user has a formatter installed for each language.

Demo of this formatter:

[image: format selection demo]

Comment: Thank you very much - all of your suggestions worked

Comment: @Harry_Hopkinson Please review https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work.   I actually spent a fair amount of time on this answer ;>}

Comment: I do not have enough reputation to upvote

Comment: See the comment on your other question.  You only need 1 rep to accept an answer,  you do need more to upvote, but upvoting (click on the up/down arrows) and accepting (click on the green check mark)  are two different things.  Please review the meta link to see how to accept answers and the importance of doing so.  Thanks.